# ADAL bearer token does not return username but aad client id

Tags: c#, .net, azure, model-view-controller, adal

We have an desktop app which uses adal to authenticate the user, using this code:

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
var context = new  AuthenticationContext(aadTenantDomain);
result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId, returnUrl, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
```

This works fine and the returned AuthenticationResult has all the right user information. Now we call a web app web api controller hosted on azure with the access token obtained from AuthenticationResult:

```
var Client = new HttpClient();
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

Which also correctly authorizes the user. Now in the web controller we use User.Identity.Name to get the username which was authorized by the access token. For many month til yesterday this worked well, but today User.Identity.Name returns the client id of the desktop app instead of a username. Anyone knows what migh be wrong?

This is the api auth configuration:

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {                   
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,                     
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role,                         
                }
            });
    }
```

And this is an example controller function:

```
[Authorize]
public class dialplanController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMe()
    {
        var Me = db.dialplan.FirstOrDefault(d => d.email == User.Identity.Name);
        return Ok(Me);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the token contains the username?

Comment: @juunas I just checked and the upn field und unique_name field both contain the username.

Comment: Could you add your authentication code from the API to the question?

Comment: @juunas I've added the api auth configuration code and an example controller where the client api id is returned instead of an username.

Comment: Hmm, but shouldn't you be doing JWT Bearer token authentication on the API side? OIDC is for redirect-based authentication in web applications.

Comment: @juunaas I thought this is what I am doing, at least the access token which I send from the desktop apps AcquireTokenAsync is an JWT bearer token.

Comment: But your API has `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` instead of `app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication()` that is typically used to authenticate AAD JWTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ClaimsPrincipal.Current?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn)?.Value returns the correct UPN of the current user or null if no upn is given.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the web app support both OpenIdConnection and Windows Azure Active Directory bearer token, you need to add the code `app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication()` as juunas mentioned.

For example, here is the code for your reference:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                //
                // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                //
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                RedirectToIdentityProvider= OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                MessageReceived= OnMessageReceived,
                SecurityTokenReceived= OnSecurityTokenReceived,
            },
        });

    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Audience = "",
        Tenant = "",
    });
}
```

After that we can call the web API using the token acquire from Azure AD. And the Azure Active Directory OWIN component will transform the `User.Identity.Name` from delegate-token based on the `unique_name` claim in the access_token.

Please decode the access token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) to see whether the `unique_name` is expected.